# "Life's not a wheel with chains made of steel" - What does it mean?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

What does the ending words of "[Catch the Rainbow](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/rainbow/catchtherainbow.html)" (by Rainbow) chorus mean?

If "life is not a wheel of chains made of steel", what is?

And why the singer asks to be blessed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exact lyrics are

> But life's not a wheel
>
> **With** chains made of steel

If you go for a long bicycle ("wheel") trip, especially at night, and if your bicycle's chain is not made of steel but of a brittler material, I assume you'll fear at every moment that something may go wrong and you'll ask to be saved from any misfortune ("blessed"). This is just my understanding, though.

Answer (score 0):

A wealthy girl is sleeping with some poor boy. There's the first problem. The wheel was a medieval torture device used up into the 1800s. So he's asking for blessing when dawn comes.. maybe so they aren't found out or so that he escapes torture.  Life's not a wheel with chains made of steel so bless me come the dawn. Read it as one sentence.